# Uneven List Elements in Horizontal Navigation Bar. The list elements are different heights

Tags: html, css

Can I please get help with this horizontal navigation bar? I tried to use what you all taught me before about the vertical navigation bar, but I could not get it to work.

It seems that the list elements in my horizontal navigation bar came out to different heights and maybe widths. I have double-checked my percent values and other careless errors, but I am at a loss as why this is happened. I even researched previous posts with questions about horizontal navigation bars, and I could not find my answer. But if I missed one, please let me know.

This is the link to my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/shihfa/8tsy0ms7/

```
<body>
<div class="contentwrapper">
    <!-- beginning of header element -->
    <div class="gradientheaderfooter">
        <header class="banner" role="banner">
             <h1>Good Karma Bikes</h1>

        </header>
    </div>
    <!-- end of header element -->
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul class="navbarbuttons">
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Need a Bike?</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Get Involved</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Our Impact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com">What's New</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Donate Now</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- beginning of main element -->
    <main class="main" role="main">
        <img src="images/GKBArt_Home1.jpg" alt="Good Karma Bikes Volunteers repairing bicycles at   
InnVision.">
    </main>
    <!-- end of main element -->
    <!-- beginning of aside element -->
    <aside class="sidebar" role="complementary">
        <ul class="sidebarbutton">
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Donate</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Volunteer</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Shop</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <!-- end of header element -->
</div>
```

This is a snippet of the CSS that applies to the Horizontal Nav Bar:

```
/* === Global Settings === */
@media screen {
header, main, aside, footer {
    display: block;
}
/* reset browser styles */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr,  
acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike,   
strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, 
legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, 
mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1.2;
}
ol {
    padding-left: 1.4em;
    list-style: decimal;
}
ul {
    padding-left: 1.4em;
    list-style: square;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* end reset browser styles */
/* === Layout For Page === */
body {
    background-image: url(../images/GKBBackground_Gradient1.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.contentwrapper {
    max-width: 1366px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline: 1px solid #333333;
}
.gradientheaderfooter {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, silver, green 90%);
}
.banner {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
.banner h1 {
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align: center;
}
/* === Code for NavBar Buttons Begin === */
.navbarbuttons ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbarbuttons li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 2%;
}
.navbarbuttons a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10%;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbarbuttons a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #7A991A;
}
/* === Code for NavBar Buttons Buttons End === */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navbarbuttons a:link, a:visited {
    ...
    padding: 10%; // your culprit
    ....
}
```

Setting a percentage for your padding will equate to a percentage of the width of each block. As each block is a different width, 10% will always be a different amount. Set a fixed amount instead:

```
padding: 10px;
```

or

```
padding: 0.8em;
```

Comment: If I use a pixel value, will my design still conform to the goal of responsive web design?

Comment: Certainly. Your `<li>` widths will never change, no matter the size of your screen. Not everything needs to (or should be) relative to container widths - especially padding or margin.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your solution out tomorrow when I work on my site again. I have a final tomorrow to study for, then back to the site. I am sure that it will work though.